# How do I change the browser that gnome terminal opens links with?

Tags: firefox, browser, google-chrome, gnome-terminal

I'd like gnome-terminal to open links with the Chrome browser, but it insists on opening them with Firefox.

I've followed both pieces of advice found here without any success:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/gnome-terminal-default-browser-332934/

My OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Are you sure you followed the last piece of advice there? Most gnome-applications abide to the default browser set there...

Comment: If you have gnome. The last piece should work.

Comment: Following Menu > System > Preferences > Internet does not work even after your reloaded gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 7):

You should choose the default browser: `Chromium Web Browser` in your case.

`Go to System --> Administration --> Preferred Applications`

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Perl Pusher, please try this and accept the answer if it works. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 13.04, couldn't find an answer online (this question is the closest I found), and eventually fixed the problem by running:

```
gnome-control-center info
```

and using the 'default applications' in there to select my browser.

Comment: Works for me (but used mate-control-center in Mint).  When I followed the other answer, it was already set to chrome.  Weird and annoying to have two different preferred apps settings pages :(  smells like a bug to me

Comment: Same panel exists in unity-control-center, under the "Defaults" item.

Answer (score 2):

Control centers are very window manager specific. In newer gnome based releases gio can handle the mime handler settings, to set a handler for URLs use this command for instance:

> gio mime x-scheme-handler/http chromium-browser.desktop