# How to change default browser AND the command line parameters used to open a link from gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, default-browser

I basically have the same question that was answered over here:

[How do I change the browser that gnome terminal opens links with?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42344/how-do-i-change-the-browser-that-gnome-terminal-opens-links-with)

Except I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and am interested in customizing the command line arguments passed to the browser. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would assume that you could launch the browser with your own script which includes your customizations and fool the system into using your script to launch your browser. Sorry, I've never done this exactly. If you are using firefox you may find this helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Programs use a variety of other programs to determine the default browser - `sensible-browser` & `xdg-open` being two of them.

For `xdg-open`, you can use it simply by by running `xdg-open http://URL`, so `xdg-open https://www.google.co.uk` will open Google for instance.
This should be the same as running `echo https://www.google.co.uk` in terminal and clicking on the link should open the default browser (in my case, Firefox).

You can see what is the default browser using `xdg-settings get default-web-browser`:

```
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
firefox.desktop
```

To set values, you do `xdg-settings set default-web-browser LAUNCHER-FILE.desktop`:

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

So now running `echo https://www.google.co.uk` and clicking on the link or running `xdg-open https://www.google.co.uk` should open Google in the new default browser (in my case now Chromium).

Notice that it links to the program's .desktop file not it's command - this needs to be a valid file in `/usr/share/applications` (or `~/.local/share/applications`). You can easily create your own with a custom command easily by copying a existing one and changing the 'Name' and 'Exec' lines:

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-new-window.desktop
$ gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-new-window.desktop & disown

##Then change Name and Exec lines to `Name=Firefox (New Window)` & `Exec=firefox --new-window %u` respectively
$ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox-new-window.desktop
```

In the above I created a new launcher, edited it so it would launch a new window  of Firefox, and updated the database of launcher files and set it to default. Now running `xdg-open https://www.google.co.uk` opens a new window of Firefox.

More info:

- [Desktop Entry Specifaction](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) (how-to edit launchers)
- [How to set which application is launched by xdg-open? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/18418/178596)
- [How to properly and easy configure `xdg-open` without any enviroment? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36380/52956)