# How can I change which browser gets opened from Terminal?

Tags: google-chrome, default-browser

I've already seen this old question from 2011: [How do I change the browser that gnome terminal opens links with?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42344/how-do-i-change-the-browser-that-gnome-terminal-opens-links-with)

and also [How can I manually change the default web browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100693/how-can-i-manually-change-the-default-web-browser)

And I've already set my default browser to Chrome. To prove it, I run `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` and see the result `google-chrome.desktop`.

If I click URLs from emails or documents or even within the Terminal's output, they properly open in Chrome.

But running commands in terminal (such as to run a local webserver of a React app) continues to open my Brave browser, which I don't want.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1386383/edit) your question to include the terminal command(s) that you are running.

Comment: see the .env file in each react app file. It will have a BROWSER= tag or if not you can add it.

Comment: Perhaps `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`  will cope with this.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks. That looked promising, especially since it showed "auto mode" as selected, which was `/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable`. I changed it to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` but unfortunately it still opened Brave.

Comment: Can you specify more precisely when it goes wrong? With which commands does it go wrong?